# Resource file getting corrupted if something is changed

Tags: c#, resources, corrupt

I have downloaded project and built it with Visual Studio 2015. Then I wanted to change few form properties and icon, but file gets corrupted. Without any resource changes to original project it will compile fine. (I replaced `=>` on get and set for one string because I use C# 6.0) But when I change anything resource related I get this additional `>>` and some weird stuff :

[image]

Project is: https://github.com/ravibpatel/CrashReporter.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because that Form contains manually added string resources. Every time you change something in your Form, Visual Studio regenerates the Form's RESX file. That means anything you add to it manually will be lost when you change any property of the form. It is best to add your string resource to Project's Resource file.